# Changing date format in Spark returns incorrect result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-format

I am trying to convert a string type date from a csv file to date format first and then to convert that to a particularly expected date format. While doing so, for a row (for the first time) I saw the date format change is changing the year value.

```
scala> df1.filter($"pt" === 2720).select("`date`").show()
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|24/08/2019|
|30/12/2019|
+----------+


scala> df1.filter($"pt" === 2720).select(date_format(to_date($"`date`","dd/MM/yyyy"),"YYYY-MM-dd")).show()
+------------------------------------------------------+
|date_format(to_date(`date`, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), YYYY-MM-dd)|
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                            2019-08-24|
|                                            2020-12-30|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see above, in the above, the two rows of data has 24/08/2019 and 30/12/2019 respectively, but after explicit type casting and date format change, it gives 2019-08-24 (which is correct) and 2020-12-30 (incorrect and unexpected).

Why does this problem occur and how can this be best avoided?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by changing the capital YYYY to yyyy in the expected date format parameter.

So, instead of

```
df1.filter($"pt" === 2720).select(date_format(to_date($"`date`","dd/MM/yyyy"),"YYYY-MM-dd")).show()
```

I am now doing

```
df1.filter($"pt" === 2720).select(date_format(to_date($"`date`","dd/MM/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
```

This is because, as per this [Java's SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the capital Y is parsed as **week year** where as small letter y is parsed as **year**.

So, now, when I ran with small y in the year's field, I get the expected result:

```
scala> df1.filter($"pt" === 2720).select(date_format(to_date($"`date`","dd/MM/yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
+------------------------------------------------------+
|date_format(to_date(`date`, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), yyyy-MM-dd)|
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                            2019-08-24|
|                                            2019-12-30|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time debugging and not founding what's wrong. You get wrong results indeed with this yyyy vs. YYYY, yet it is too subtle to just find easily that this is the cause. Thanks a lot!